# using predict with a list of lm() objects

Tags: r, plyr, lm, predict

I have data which I regularly run regressions on. Each "chunk" of data gets fit a different regression. Each state, for example, might have a different function that explains the dependent value. This seems like a typical "split-apply-combine" type of problem so I'm using the plyr package. I can easily create a list of `lm()` objects which works well. However I can't quite wrap my head around how I use those objects later to predict values in a separate data.frame.

Here's a totally contrived example illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```
# setting up some fake data
set.seed(1)
funct <- function(myState, myYear){
   rnorm(1, 100, 500) +  myState + (100 * myYear) 
}
state <- 50:60
year <- 10:40
myData <- expand.grid( year, state)
names(myData) <- c("year","state")
myData$value <- apply(myData, 1, function(x) funct(x[2], x[1]))
## ok, done with the fake data generation. 

require(plyr)

modelList <- dlply(myData, "state", function(x) lm(value ~ year, data=x))
## if you want to see the summaries of the lm() do this:  
    # lapply(modelList, summary)

state <- 50:60
year <- 50:60
newData <- expand.grid( year, state)
names(newData) <- c("year","state") 
## now how do I predict the values for newData$value 
   # using the regressions in modelList?
```

So how do I use the `lm()` objects contained in `modelList` to predict values using the year and state independent values from `newData`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
predNaughty <- ddply(newData, "state", transform,
  value=predict(modelList[[paste(piece$state[1])]], newdata=piece))
head(predNaughty)
#   year state    value
# 1   50    50 5176.326
# 2   51    50 5274.907
# 3   52    50 5373.487
# 4   53    50 5472.068
# 5   54    50 5570.649
# 6   55    50 5669.229
predDiggsApproved <- ddply(newData, "state", function(x)
  transform(x, value=predict(modelList[[paste(x$state[1])]], newdata=x)))
head(predDiggsApproved)
#   year state    value
# 1   50    50 5176.326
# 2   51    50 5274.907
# 3   52    50 5373.487
# 4   53    50 5472.068
# 5   54    50 5570.649
# 6   55    50 5669.229
```

**JD Long edit**

I was inspired enough to work out an `adply()` option:

```
pred3 <- adply(newData, 1,  function(x)
    predict(modelList[[paste(x$state)]], newdata=x))
head(pred3)
#   year state        1
# 1   50    50 5176.326
# 2   51    50 5274.907
# 3   52    50 5373.487
# 4   53    50 5472.068
# 5   54    50 5570.649
# 6   55    50 5669.229
```

Comment: that totally nails it! Thank you mucho. Can you explain where the data.frame `piece` comes from? Is it autogenerated by ddply?

Comment: @JDLong: `.fun` is ultimately called on a data frame named `piece`.  But, as @BrianDiggs pointed out in chat, this shouldn't be relied upon.  Better to wrap in an anonymous function (see my update).

Comment: hi, if you could have a look at my question it would be great http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427392/apply-predict-between-data-frames-within-two-lists . thanks!

Comment: @JDLong Am I able to get standard errors using this approach?

Comment: @juliamm2011 I think all you have to do is turn `se.fit=TRUE` per this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33660779/37751

note that we're now 8 years after this question was answered and I would no longer be using `adply` any longer but rather would probably use `broom`

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `mdply` to supply both the model and the data to each function call:

```
dataList <- dlply(newData, "state")

preds <- mdply(cbind(mod = modelList, df = dataList), function(mod, df) {
  mutate(df, pred = predict(mod, newdata = df))
})
```

Answer (score 6):

A solution with just `base` R. The format of the output is different, but all the values are right there.

```
models <- lapply(split(myData, myData$state), 'lm', formula = value ~ year)
pred4  <- mapply('predict', models, split(newData, newData$state))
```

Comment: thanks @ramnath. I really like comparing base R solutions to those done with packages. It helps me both improve my base R understanding as well as understand the compromises I am making when using abstractions like plyr.

Comment: And this is how I normally solve the problem - but with `dlply` and `mdply`

Comment: @hadley Could you show a worked example for this case?  I tried building one with `mdply` and could not figure out how to do it because `.data` has to be a matrix or data.frame, and the two arguments to `predict` are an `lm` object and a `data.frame`.  I couldn't stuff a list of `lm` objects as a column in a `data.frame`. The other approach I tried, making `.data` a list of lists, (`.data=list(object=modelList, newData=newDataList)` where `newDataList <- dlply(newData, .(state), identity)`) didn't work because `.data` wasn't a matrix or data.frame (as per the documentation).

Comment: In brief, cbind the two lists together

Answer (score 4):

What is wrong with

```
lapply(modelList, predict, newData)
```

?

EDIT:

Thanks for explaining what is wrong with that.  How about:

```
newData <- data.frame(year)
ldply(modelList, function(model) {
  data.frame(newData, predict=predict(model, newData))
})
```

Iterate over the models, and apply the new data (which is the same for each state since you just did an `expand.grid` to create it).

EDIT 2:

If `newData` does not have the same values for `year` for every `state` as in the example, a more general approach can be used.  Note that this uses the original definition of `newData`, not the one in the first edit.

```
ldply(state, function(s) {
  nd <- newData[newData$state==s,]
  data.frame(nd, predict=predict(modelList[[as.character(s)]], nd))
})
```

First 15 lines of this output:

```
   year state  predict
1    50    50 5176.326
2    51    50 5274.907
3    52    50 5373.487
4    53    50 5472.068
5    54    50 5570.649
6    55    50 5669.229
7    56    50 5767.810
8    57    50 5866.390
9    58    50 5964.971
10   59    50 6063.551
11   60    50 6162.132
12   50    51 5514.825
13   51    51 5626.160
14   52    51 5737.496
15   53    51 5848.832
```

Comment: that's exactly the sort of thing I keep cooking up, but it's not really what I'm after. That applies every model to every state. I only want the model where state==50 to be applied to the data where state==50

Answer (score 2):

I take it the hard part is matching each state in `newData` to the corresponding model.

Something like this perhaps?

```
predList <- dlply(newData, "state", function(x) {
  predict(modelList[[as.character(min(x$state))]], x) 
})
```

Here I used a "hacky" way of extracting the corresponding state model: `as.character(min(x$state))`

...There is probably a better way?

Output:

```
> predList[1:2]
$`50`
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11 
5176.326 5274.907 5373.487 5472.068 5570.649 5669.229 5767.810 5866.390 5964.971 6063.551 6162.132 

$`51`
      12       13       14       15       16       17       18       19       20       21       22 
5514.825 5626.160 5737.496 5848.832 5960.167 6071.503 6182.838 6294.174 6405.510 6516.845 6628.181
```

Or, if you want a `data.frame` as output:

```
predData <- ddply(newData, "state", function(x) {
  y <-predict(modelList[[as.character(min(x$state))]], x)
  data.frame(id=names(y), value=c(y))
})
```

Output:

```
head(predData)
  state id    value
1    50  1 5176.326
2    50  2 5274.907
3    50  3 5373.487
4    50  4 5472.068
5    50  5 5570.649
6    50  6 5669.229
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I believe `lmList` is the ideal tool here,

```
library(nlme)
ll = lmList(value ~ year | state, data=myData)
predict(ll, newData)


## Or, to show that it produces the same results as the other proposed methods...
newData[["value"]] <- predict(ll, newData)
head(newData)
#   year state    value
# 1   50    50 5176.326
# 2   51    50 5274.907
# 3   52    50 5373.487
# 4   53    50 5472.068
# 5   54    50 5570.649
# 6   55    50 5669.229
```

Comment: Uh, yeah, that does seem best! Really nice that `lmList` has its own `predict()` method.