# Use list of models to calculate new values in a data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe, plyr, reshape2

Using dlply [(from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214432/1670053); code below) I am able to generate a list of linear models on subsets of my data.frame.  Now that I have this list, I would like to use the models to generate values in another data.frame.

The list contains a model for each `DAY` and `variable` subset. I would like to apply the model to the same subsets in another data.frame.  For example, for `DAY` == 1 and variable == `Var.1` the model (y = mx+b) is `value = -4.521869(Location) + 21.315`. Using the model for the appropriate subsets, I would calculate values for `Var.1` in another data.frame (e.g. `dat_rec` which already has entries for `DAY` and `Location`).

Is there a way to use the models from the list on the same subsets in another data.frame (e.g. use the model to for `DAY` == 1 and `variable` == Var.1 to populate values in the data.frame everywhere[e.g. different `Sites`] `DAY` == 1 and `variable` == Var.1) Is there a similar list method to populate a data.frame with the values calculated using the models from the list? The desired end product (i.e. `dat_rec` below) is data.frame.

```
# Data
dat <- structure(list(Site = c(32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
32L, 32L, 32L, 32L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), Location = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), DAY = c(5L, 
55L, 555L, 5555L, 5L, 55L, 555L, 5555L, 5L, 55L, 555L, 5555L, 
5L, 55L, 555L, 5555L), Var.1 = c(20.9, 20.8, 21.03, 21.36, 21.73, 
21.18, 20.73, 21.98, 21.73, 12.48702448, 12.19642662, 12.33218874, 
11.85626285, 11.88812108, 12.70549981, 11.89587521), Var.2 = c(100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 91L, 
92L, 88L, 89L, 90L), Var.3 = c(14.47, 14.4, 14.3, 14.14, 14.72, 
14.62, 14.14, 14.49, 10.27287765, 10.27287765, 10.41763527, 10.51725376, 
11.12918753, 10.81166867, 10.80656509, 11.00093898), Var.4 = c(890.19, 
888.9, 889.14, 888.15, 889.57, 888.41, 887.48, 886.87, 688.15, 
698.23, 650.99, 700.01, 699, 689.6, 658.7, 689.99)), .Names = c("Site", 
"Location", "DAY", "Var.1", "Var.2", "Var.3", "Var.4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))

# melt data for use with dlply
mdat <- melt(dat, id=c("DAY", "Site", "Location"))

# this dlply solution was built from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/1214432/1670053
models_mdat <- dlply(mdat, c("DAY","variable"), function(df) 
                lm(value ~ Location, data = df))

# example (partial) result, with Var.1 filled in for two DAYs
# I've only filled in the values for Var.1 using the model from the list 
# for DAY 5 and 55.
# not melted
dat_rec <- structure(list(Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Location = c(0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), DAY = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 55L, 
55L, 55L, 55L), Var.1 = c(20.8628131, 20.4106262, 19.9584393, 
19.5062524, 20.1097573, 19.2295146, 18.3492719, 17.4690292), 
    Var.2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Var.3 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Var.4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Site", "Location", "DAY", "Var.1", 
"Var.2", "Var.3", "Var.4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
# melted
    dat_rec_melt <- structure(list(Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Location = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.4), DAY = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Var.1", 
"Var.2", "Var.3", "Var.4"), class = "factor"), value = c(20.8628131, 
20.4106262, 19.9584393, 19.5062524, 20.1097573, 19.2295146, 18.3492719, 
17.4690292, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Site", 
"Location", "DAY", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -32L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `predict`:

```
sapply(models_mdat ,predict,newdata=dat_rec)
```

**EDIT** get the result aligned with new datas:

```
lapply(models_mdat ,function(x)
       cbind(dat_rec,fit=predict(x,newdata=dat_rec)))
```

Comment: `predict` seems like it is what I want.  However, is it possible to use one of the `apply` functions with losing the rest of the info in `data_rec`? Using `sapply` as above results in solution that does not keep the info from `data_rec`. How do I get/keep the info from `sapply` to be aligned with `data_rec`?

Comment: Thanks. This is closer to the result I was looking for above.  I will continue to read about the different `apply` procedures to see if I can arrive at a solution that approximates `data_rec` above. A result where the list of models is used to build a data.frame (e.g. data_rec), or to build one list. I am not trying to build a separate list/data.frame for each model in the model list, but rather use each model to build upon one.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you are looking for, but maybe you can use the combine the result of `res <- lapply(models_mdat ,..)` using `do.call(cbind,res)`

Comment: I will explore the suggestions in your latest comment.  In an effort to be clearer... my desired end product is a data.frame that has been updated with values calculated from models contained in the list of the models. The list of models was created using subsets and these same subsets should be used when updating the data.frame, e.g. the model for `DAY`==  1 & `variable` == Var.1 should be used to update the data.frame with values were its `DAY` == 1 & `variable` == Var.1, etc

Answer (score 0):

Using the information from agstudy it appears that `predict` is the tool I was looking for to calculate the values from the models.  Knowing that I wanted to use the model list generated to with `dlply` to update a data.frame with `predictions` I had a much better idea on what to search for to find a solution.

I found a solution in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8534477/1670053). To acheive the result I was looking for I need to use the model list and also the data as a list. Then predict can be used with `mdply` to finally arrive at an updated data.frame.

```
# melted
    dat_rec_melt <- structure(list(Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), Location = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 
0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 
0.4), DAY = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 55L, 55L, 55L, 55L), variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Var.1", 
"Var.2", "Var.3", "Var.4"), class = "factor"), value = c(20.8628131, 
20.4106262, 19.9584393, 19.5062524, 20.1097573, 19.2295146, 18.3492719, 
17.4690292, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Site", 
"Location", "DAY", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -32L
), class = "data.frame")

dat_rec_list <- dlply(dat_rec_melt, c("DAY", "variable"))

predictions <- mdply(cbind(mod = models_mdat, df = dat_rec_list), function(mod, df) {
  mutate(df, pred = predict(mod, newdata = df))
})
```