# Match lists for use with PREDICT: list of lm() objects and list of data

Tags: r, list, plyr, reshape2, predict

I have 18 dates (e.g. unique `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR`) and 10 variables.  I have a lm model (y = mx + b, where y = `value` and x = `pLength`) for each date and variable (180 models). These are stored in a list (i.e. `models`).

I want to use these models to predict values. I have data.frame (the data.frame to recieve the values) with the following columns,  `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR` and `pLength`, here I want to predict the value for each variable for each date/pLength combination.

For example, if the model was for date and variable combination = 7.8.2013.Var1, there should be a prediction for `Var1` for every `pLength` that occurs on 7.8.2013.

To this end, I attempted to use another list created from the receiving data.frame. This list (i.e. `rec_List`) is 152 splits of the receiving data.frame.  These splits are unique rows of `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR` and `pLength`. They are same 18 dates as above grouped with different `pLength`s. The value and number of `pLength`s vary by date.

In my current approach I attempted to use some information from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497160/using-predict-with-a-list-of-lm-objects) attempting to use lists with predict (but for only one variable). This is not working for me.  Instead of getting a prediction for each variable for each pLength by date, I end up with some haphazard predictions totaling 180, the same as the number of models.

```
# Current Output  'preds'
X1            DAY MONTH YEAR pLength value
7.8.2013.Var1 7   8     2013 0.00    0.00
7.8.2013.Var2 7   8     2013 0.25    1.07  
7.8.2013.Var3 7   8     2013 0.33    6.25
etc 

# Desired Output
X1             DAY MONTH YEAR pLength value
7.8.2013.Var1  7   8     2013 0.00    0.00
7.8.2013.Var2  7   8     2013 0.00    1.10
7.8.2013.Var3  7   8     2013 0.00    6.55
...
7.8.2013.Var10 7   8     2013 0.00    100.10
7.9.2013.Var1  7   9     2013 0.25    0.00
7.9.2013.Var2  7   9     2013 0.25    1.15 
etc
```

When saw this current output above I thought that I could perhaps duplicate the rows in recieiving data.frame list so that each `DAY`, `MONTH`, `YEAR` and `pLength` was replicated 10 times.  This did not work, but resulted in this.

```
# with duplicated rows
    X1              DAY     MONTH   YEAR    pLength         value
1   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
2   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
3   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
4   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
5   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
6   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
7   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
8   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
9   7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
10  7.8.2013.Var1   7   8   2013    0.0000000   0.000000e+00
11  7.8.2013.Var2   7   8   2013    0.2500000   1.072500e+00
```

where I was hoping rows 1 - 10 would be Var1-10 for 7.8.2013 and pLength = 0.00.

I know the problem may lie in the fact that I am cbinding unequal lists to create the predictions, but am unsure on how else to use a list of models with predict. I thought the row duplication would have helped with that.

In brief: I would like have a prediction for every date and pLength combination for each of 10 variables.  I attempting to do this with lists, because this is the only way I currently can think of doing this after asking and reading other posts.

```
# code with abbreviated data
require(plyr)
require(reshape2)
mdata2 <- structure(list(DAY = c(7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 
7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L), MONTH = c(8L, 
6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 
6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 8L, 6L), YEAR = c(2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 
2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L, 2013L, 2012L
), pLength = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L), variable = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), .Label = c("Rain", "Wind", "WindD", 
"TempA", "TempF", "RH", "FuelM", "WindMax", "PAR", "VPD"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.51, 1.096, 1.26, 1.472, 67.59440741, 
    0.153388889, 67.59440741, 0.153388889, 30.17, 31.73, 31.06, 
    31.78, 33.52, 46.9, 40.06, 43.66, 55.62, 27.81, 50.75, 27.82, 
    13.33, 0.842, 10.39, 5.783, 0.727, 1.58, 2.247, 2.234, 1105, 
    1740, 1767, 1969, 1.90257357, 3.351394626, 2.17506063, 3.373580125
    )), .Names = c("DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR", "pLength", "variable", 
"value"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 19L, 20L, 37L, 38L, 55L, 56L, 
73L, 74L, 91L, 92L, 109L, 110L, 127L, 128L, 145L, 146L, 163L, 
164L, 181L, 182L, 199L, 200L, 217L, 218L, 235L, 236L, 253L, 254L, 
271L, 272L, 289L, 290L, 307L, 308L, 325L, 326L, 343L, 344L), class = "data.frame")

vs2 <- structure(list(DAY = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), MONTH = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), YEAR = c(2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 
2013L, 2013L), pLength = c(0, 0.222222222, 0.444444444, 0.666666667, 
0.888888889, 1, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.333333333, 0.5, 0.75, 0.666666667, 
1, 1)), .Names = c("DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR", "pLength"), row.names = c("1:89", 
"1:90", "1:91", "1:92", "1:93", "1:94", "2:6", "2:23", "2:31", 
"2:39", "2:49", "2:69", "2:71", "2:87", "2:96"), class = "data.frame")

# ** code edited to reflect answer below **
models <- dlply(mdata2, c("variable", "DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR"), function(df) 
  lm(value ~ pLength, data = df))

rec_List <- dlply(unique(vs2), c("DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR"))

preds <- mdply(cbind(mod = models, df = rec_List), function(mod, df) {
  mutate(df, value = predict(mod, newdata = df))
})
```

Comment: this sounds like a job for `llply`!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when the two lists were `cbind`ed that didn't "match", their orders were different.  The `model` list was created by `Day, Month, Year, variable` whereas the `rec_List` went Day, Month, Year. In this way the `rec_List` would cycle through dates and would `models` creating the mistmatch decribed above.

By changing this line:

```
models <- dlply(mdata2, c("DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR", "variable"), function(df) 
  lm(value ~ pLength, data = df))
```

to this, with `variable` first

```
models <- dlply(mdata2, c("variable", "DAY", "MONTH", "YEAR"), function(df) 
  lm(value ~ pLength, data = df))
```

Results in the desired output. That is there is prediction for each variable for each date/pLength combination.