# Predict with a list - revisited

Tags: r, plyr, lm, dplyr

In [using predict with a list of lm() objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497160/using-predict-with-a-list-of-lm-objects/8497539#8497539), @JD Long asked for a solution to a problem which I encounter very often; typically, it comes up when models have been fit and plots are to be produced. JD Long's solution, edited in @Joshua Ulrich's answer was elegant, with the exception of the `paste` that was required.

@hadley, chief of the `ddply` empire, published a solution with `mdply` which I found incomprehensible and far from elegant.

Now the `dplyr` (and possibly `tidyr`) is taking over: is there a more intuitive way to handle this common job?

For data and sample code, see JD Long's example cited above.

Comment: did you consider `nlme::lmList`? It uses a grouping variable in the formula, which in my opinion is a very intuitive interface.

Comment: +1 @baptiste. For those who are interested, [here is a nice demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24907275/980833) of how simple `lmList()` and `predict.lmList()` make this job.

Comment: Yes, I am a heavy nlme user, predict.lmList is the sample app in background. But in Joshua's question, lm only served as an example, and a generalization to other fits, e.g. from stan/mcmc is what I am looking for.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do this elegantly with dplyr at the moment. The way I imagine it would work is that you'd use some tidyr verb to get a data frame where one column is a column of data frames (the data forming the prediction grid), you'd then join that with the data frame containing the models, then `do(predict(.$model, .$data))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the data in the cited [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8497160/using-predict-with-a-list-of-lm-objects/8497539), you can use the following approach with dplyr.

```
library(dplyr)
newData %>% 
      group_by(state) %>%
      mutate(pred = predict(modelList[[as.character(state[1])]], 
                            as.data.frame(year)))
```

However, I am not sure whether this solution is more elegant than the existing ones.

Comment: That will serve as an accepted answer, if there is no better one. In my eye, the two casts are an indication that the solution is not really elegant; as.character(state[1]) (or paste in the original version) has a bit of a code smell.